# Protractor: how to Force secuential execution of describe?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using protractor to test an webapp, there is a lot of test_.js and it looks like all test are running at the same time. if I set just one test in the export.config.specs it works flawlessly but if I use wildcard or put 2 or more spects it open the browser and try to open all the routes at the same time and fails all test...

**So is there a flag or something that I miss to force execute all describes one by one?**

An excerpt of my conf file:

```
exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: [
        {'browserName': 'chrome'}
    ],
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    params: {
        domain: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/'
    },
    specs: [
        'specs/test_login.js',
        //'specs/test_*.js'
    ]
};
```

an example of one of the many specs:

```
describe('homepage test', function() {
  browser.get(browser.params.domain);
  it('should check page title', function() {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('The title');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser actions must be allwais within a Jasmin action like
`it`
`before(All/Each)`
`after(All/Each)`

Solution based on example:

```
describe('homepage test', function() {
  beforeAll(function() {
   browser.get(browser.params.domain);
  });
  it('should check page title', function() {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('The title');
  });
});
```

source: http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the describes to run sequentially in the same browser window, in  `exports.config`, under `multiCapabilities` (or `capabilities`) add `shardTestFiles: false`

If you want all the describes to run one at a time in separate browser windows, in  `exports.config`, add `maxSessions: 1`

Comment: I already try those settings, and those are the the default values